# Sqlite Timestamp various compare

Tags: sql, sqlite, timestamp

How is it possible to compare a `TIMESTAMP` column by date or time?

I try to retrieve records that difference of `TIMESTAMP` column and `NOW` are a week or 2 hours or less 30 minutes.

```
SELECT FROM Tcase WHERE (date_time-datetime('now'))<7day
SELECT FROM Tcase WHERE (date_time-datetime('now'))<1hour
```

Comment: interval should be in day or hour or seconds form?! i mean its 7*24*3600?

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
SELECT * FROM Tcase
WHERE datetime(date_time,'-7 day', '+5 hour', '+10 minute') >= date('now')
```

### Edit

```
SELECT * FROM Tcase
date('now') > datetime(date_time,'+7 day')
OR date('now') < datetime(date_time,'-7 day')
```

### See [SQLite date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

### [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ba5d7/1)

Comment: sqllite can determine "+7 day" what does mean?! oh yeah you are using modifires?! how is it for campare by hour and minute?!

Comment: i execute this query,but it return nothing !